# Pass a value from JSP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps

I am working with google maps and I am trying to pass a value from my database (Access) to my javascript code.

I have

```
var centerPoint = new GLatLng( <% Double.parseDouble(myclass.getLatitude()); %> , <% Double.parseDouble(myclass.getLongitude()); %>);
```

where myclass.getLatitude() returns a string representation of my latitude and I convert it to double etc...

But the problem is the map does not display.

Answer (score 3):

There is little point in using `Double.parseDouble()` as it'll get immediately converted right back to `String`. But your problem is you're not printing the coordinates (`<%` wraps java scriptlet; `<%=` **outputs** the result of expression evaluation). This should do it:

```
var centerPoint = new GLatLng( <%= myclass.getLatitude() %> , <%= myclass.getLongitude() %>);
```